# java - compare two date values for the month and year

Tags: java, date, date-comparison

I have a requirement to match two dates and if their month/year are same, i should return true, otherwise false. Based on my search, i found the following solution. Is there any other better way to do this comparison?.

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1);
    cal2.setTime(date2);
    boolean sameDay = cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
                      cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Comment: This Question should be re-opened, as it is not "unclear". The Question asks how to tell if a pair of dates share the same year and month. Pretty simple question, and a reasonable one. For example, do two credit cards share the same expiration year-month.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## tl;dr

> match two dates and if their month/year are same
>
> Is there any other better way to do this comparison?

Yes, the better way uses the modern *java.time* classes.

```
YearMonth.from(                                   // Represent the year-month without a day-of-month, without a time-of-day, and without a time zone.
    LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ,   // Represent a date-only, without a time-of-day and without a time zone.
)                                                 // Returns a `YearMonth` object.
.equals(                                          // Compare one `YearMonth` object to another.
    YearMonth.now()                               // Capture today’s year-month as seen in the JVM’s current default time zone.
)
```

## Details

Yes, there is a better way.

You are using old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. These classes have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them, including java.util.Date.

## java.time

Those old classes have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

### `Instant`

Convert the given java.util.Date objects to [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) objects, a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCoordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant i1 = myJavaUtilDate1.toInstant();
Instant i2 = myJavaUtilDate2.toInstant();
```

We are aiming to get to [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) objects as you only care about the year and the month. But to get there we need to apply a time zone. The year and the month only have meaning in the context of a specific time zone, and unless you are from [Iceland](http://time.is/Iceland) I doubt you want the year/month context of UTC.

### `ZoneId`

So we need to specify the desired/expected time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Apply that time zone to each `Instant`, producing [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) objects.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( i1 , zoneId );
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( i2 , zoneId );
```

### `YearMonth`

Now extract `YearMonth` objects.

```
YearMonth ym1 = YearMonth.from( zdt1 );
YearMonth ym2 = YearMonth.from( zdt2 );
```

Compare.

```
Boolean same = ym1.equals( ym2 );
```

By the way, you likely have other business logic involving the year and month. Remember that the java.time classes are built into Java now. So you can use and pass `YearMonth` objects throughout your code base rather than re-calculating or passing strings.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Fast way:**
With JodaTime libary.

- First, make sure that you downloaded/implemented it.
- Then import.

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;
```

- Here you go:

```
Date Date1 = new Date();
Date Date2 = new Date();

if (new LocalDate(Date1).getYear() == new LocalDate(Date2).getYear()) {
 // Year Matches
 if (new LocalDate(Date1).getMonthOfYear() == new LocalDate(Date2).getMonthOfYear()) {
  // Year and Month Matches
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date1.getYear() == date2.getYear() && date1.getMonth() == date2.getMonth()`

Comment: getYear() etc are Deprecated

Comment: `getYear()` and `getMonth()` are not only deprecated, they have been deprecated sine February 1997 because they work unreliably across time zones. And the whole `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated. If you cannot avoid getting one, convert to `ZonedDateTime` as shown in the answer by Basil Bourque.